# WAR copied to Tomcat FarmWarDeployer watched dir won't deploy

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to make FarmWarDeployer to work but can't. At logs where watchEnabled="true" I can see:

```
INFO: Cluster deployment is watching [/tmp/war-listen/] for changes.
.
.
.
    
INFO: Installing webapp [/Sample2] from [/tmp/war-deploy/Sample2.war]
```

But after this, just nothing.
Of course my second node doesn't receive any notifacation.

This is my main server configuration, using Multicast to sync between nodes.

> ```
> <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" 
>                          channelSendOptions="8">
>
>          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
>                             expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
>                             notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
>  
>          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
>   
>          <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
>                                             address="228.0.0.4"
>                                             port="45564"
>                                             frequency="500"
>                                             dropTime="3000"/>
>
>                      <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
>                        <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
>                      </Sender>
>    
>                       <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
>                                        address="auto"
>                                        port="4001"
>                                        autoBind="100"
>                                       selectorTimeout="5000"
>                                       maxThreads="6"/>
>      
>                    <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
>                    <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
>           </Channel>
>
>
> <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
>                     tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
>                     deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
>                     watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
>                     watchEnabled="true"/>
>
>
>        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=""/>
>        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
>  
>       <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
>       <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/> 
> </Cluster> <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
>                prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
>                pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
>  </Host>
> ```

Already tried permissions but no luck.

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat tomcat 44 Mar 10 11:32 war-deploy
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat tomcat 44 Mar 10 11:32 war-listen
drwxrwxr-x 2 tomcat tomcat  6 Mar  9 18:51 war-temp
```

The account that uploads the file via SCP is admin_platform, not root. The tomcat is running as root.

When I restart main Tomcat it says this about the WAR:

```
INFO: webapp [/Sample2] are already deployed.
```

Which is not true as I can't see it at the management console (/manager) or access it via browser.

Any clue what else can I try or am I missing?

Thanks

PS: Can both servers be watchEnabled = "true"?